# Mark a GitHub Actions workflow as success even if a step fails

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following workflow outline

```yaml
jobs:
  
  job1:
 
    steps:
  
    - name: step 1 of job 1
      run: exit 1

  job2:
  if: failure()
  
    steps:

    - name: step 1 of job 2
      run: echo "Hello World"
```

I know the above runs. However it marks my corresponding status check as failed (red color). Is there a way to make the action execution successful?

Comment: Catch it in the first step, so that step _doesn't_ fail?

Comment: I want everything in the above file to run, including `job2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [continue-on-error](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error) step option:

> jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].continue-on-error
>
> Prevents a job from failing
> when a step fails. Set to true to allow a job to pass when this step
> fails

You. could check the `outcome` of the step in order to understand if was failed or not like:

```
steps.<id>.outcome != 'success'
```

See [outcome](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#steps-context) doc here

Comment: But wouldn't this mean the second job, which runs `if: failure()`, _wouldn't_ run, because the previous job didn't actually fail?

Comment: you can use `if: success() || failure()` or `if: always()` see also https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#status-check-functions

Comment: Sure, but you don't mention that change and it means the job runs unconditionally rather than conditionally, which fundamentally changes the behaviour.